Handle multiple subplots distributed unequally which share x value


This is the first question I am writing, sorry if something is not correct.
I'am trying to plot several subplots in same figure:

They can't be plotted in a squared grid because each row rapresent a certain combination of measured value and i need to keep them like that
Each row contains different number of columns in function of the plotting combination which unable me to use fig.tight_layout() (I get the following error--> UserWarning: tight_layout not applied: number of columns in subplot specifications must be multiples of one another.)
Each subplot has the same x value common for all subplots in all figures for all the folders.

Maybe there is a way to do apply something similar to fig.tight_layout (maybe not on the figure but on the image after saving it as png)?
Also it would be great to have a legend but there is no space to place it so if you have any idea on how to generate a visible legend that would be great. Right now I prefered to have a dataframe or file which acts as legend.
        def gen_figAx(dic, lvl_1, i_, folder_results_path):
            x_val = 'Time_min'
            
            for k1, v1 in dic.items():
                
                fig = plt.figure(figsize = choose_size, clear=True)
                
                if len(v1) == 0:
                    nosubgroups(k1, lvl_1, x_val, folder_results_path, fig)
                    continue
                
                else:
                    
                    n_rows = len(v1.keys())
                    c = 0
                    this_is_the_row_number = 0
                    remember_me = 0
                    
                    
                    for k2, v2 in v1.items():
                        n_cols = len(v2)
                        
                        for k3, v3 in v2.items():
                            skip_me = False
                            for _finally in v3:
                                if _finally not in lvl_1.columns:
                                    skip_me = True
                                    break
                            
                            if skip_me:
                                continue
                            
                            if remember_me != v2:
                                grid = np.arange(1,n_rows*n_cols+1).reshape(n_rows, n_cols)
                                c = grid[this_is_the_row_number][0]
                                this_is_the_row_number += 1
                                
                                
                            ax = fig.add_subplot(n_rows, n_cols, c)
                            
                            for _finally in v3:
                                ax.plot(lvl_1[x_val], lvl_1[_finally], label = _finally)
                                    
                            ax.set_title(k2+' '+k3, fontweight="bold")
                            #ax.legend()
                            c += 1
                            remember_me = v2
                            
                    fig.suptitle(k1, fontsize = 15)
                    dir_ = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(folder_results_path, k1 +'.png'))                  
                    plt.subplot_tool()
                    plt.savefig(dir_)
                    plt.close(fig)

What didn't work:
plt.rcParams['figure.constrained_layout.use'] = True
fig.tight_layout

Right now I am using plt.subplot_tool(), adjusting each figure manually (I have 7 figures to manually adjust) exporting the results and then insert them in plt.subplot_adjust(top, bottom, left,right,hspace,wspace).

Have you tried subplot_mosaic?  Also note that you should not call tight_layout if using constrained layout because they are mutually exclusive, so calling tight_layout actually turns constrained layout off.

I'lll give a look to subplot_mosaic thank you for the hint. Yes I know they can't work together, I meant that I used both of them as single lines and they didn't work. They both gave: UserWarning: tight_layout not applied: number of columns in subplot specifications must be multiples of one another.
